# Is column [x] number if so do convert to a number [y] or return blank

Tags: office365, business-intelligence, dax, powerbi

I have a really basic excel spreadsheet imported into PowerBI. Here is the data in powerBi[image]

The response column will have either text a number in it. I need an additional column to covert it to either a number or return blank.

This is the formula i currently have:

```
Column = IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1[Response]),VALUE(Sheet1[Response]),BLANK())
```

This always returns blank, and `ISNUMBER(Sheet1[Response])` or `ISNUMBER([Response])` always returns false.

Any ideas where i am going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I had this problem and clumsily did this, but it worked.

```
Column = IFERROR(value([response]),blank())
```

Comment: Edited it to match my example and fix a typo. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `value` to the `if` statement will resolve number stored as text:

```
Column = IF(ISNUMBER(value(Sheet1[Response])),VALUE(Sheet1[Response]),BLANK())
```

Comment: This throws a `#Error` since it can't convert the nonnumbers to numbers with the `value(Sheet1[Response])`